# mysql path environment variable not working

Tags: mysql, django, visual-studio-code, backend

I am trying to connect mysql to the back end of my project in Django
When I use the command mysql -u root -p I receive this error:

'mysql : The term 'mysql' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.'

I have installed mysql, configured it and additionally set the PATH in the environment variables windows panel. C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\

when I search this error I only see to change the PATH but it is already done, I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: Why do you want to use mysql's cli if you program in python?

Comment: @shadow I don't necessarily want to use it, but its a requirement for the project that is a part of the course I am enrolled in.

Comment: Why don't you use a python mysql connector?

Comment: @shadow because I have to do exactly what the course instructs me to do, I don't have a choice to do workarounds. It's part of the coursera meta backend web developer certification.